# Arraylist with two types: how to determine the first type?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new to the arraylists and would like to ask how would i know if a passed into the parameter array is of which type (String, Int, Double..) and how could i handle in the following method?:

```
public static <T> Pair<T, Integer> mode(T items[])
```

The second type is always a set of `Integers`, but the T (the first type) can be any other type such as Integer, Double, String...etc. I need to extract the amount of the most often characters(or numbers, or Strings..) passed into the method. In the test file I have smth like this:

```
 @Test(timeout=2000) public void string_mode_3(){
    test_mode(new String[]{"b","a","b","a","b","c","b"},
              "b",4);
```

or

```
@Test(timeout=2000) public void integer_mode_1(){
    test_mode(new Integer[]{30,10,10,20},
              10,2);
```

How would I have to find out if the first type is Integer, Double, String in the method `mode()` ?

```
public class Pair<X,Y>{
  private X first;
  private Y second;

  public Pair(X x, Y y){
    this.first = x;
    this.second = y;
  }

  public X getFirst(){
    return this.first;
  }
  public Y getSecond(){
    return this.second;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(!(o instanceof Pair)){
      return false;
    }
    Pair p = (Pair) o;
    return
      this.first.equals(p.first) &&
      this.second.equals(p.second);
  }

  public String toString(){
    return String.format("(%s,%s)",first,second);
  }

}

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Mode {

    public static <T> Pair<T, Integer> mode(T items[])
    {
        return 
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to know the type of the array elements to achieve this. Note that you only need to count how many times each element appear, it doesn't matter what type they are.

This is one of the advantages of using generics: you can create code that can transparently be used with many different types.

Something like this would work:

```
public static <T> Pair<T, Integer> mode(T items[]) {
    // If the array is empty, return a dummy pair object
    if (items.length == 0) {
        return new Pair(null, 0);
    }

    // Create a map to store the elements count
    Map<T, Integer> countFromItem = new HashMap<>();
    // For each item in the array
    for (T item : items) {
        // Get the current count
        Integer count = countFromItem.get(item);
        // If there is no current count
        if (count == null) {
            // Set the count to 0
            count = 0;
        }
        // Add 1 to the item current count
        countFromItem.put(item, count + 1);
    }

    // After we found correct count for each element
    T mode =  null;
    int maxCount = 0;
    // Go through each entry (element: count) in the map
    for (Map.Entry<T, Integer> entry : countFromItem.entrySet()) {
        // If the this entry count is greater than the greatest count until now
        if (entry.getValue() > maxCount) {
            // This entry element is the mode
            mode = entry.getKey();
            // This entry count is the maxCount
            maxCount = entry.getValue();
        }
    }
    return new Pair(mode, maxCount);
}
```

Comment: I understood your way of doing but I've already done smth similar without maps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try instanceOf to check what type the objec. For generics you can use Integer, Double objects and do a check on this .. Just a hack :) happy coding..
Edit : Attaching one of my code for your reference

```
if (objectVal instanceof Double) {
                errors.add(CommonValidatorUtil.isNegative(field.getName(), (Double) field.get(obj)));
            } else if (objectVal instanceof Long) {
                errors.add(CommonValidatorUtil.isNegative(field.getName(), (Long) field.get(obj)));
            } else if (objectVal instanceof String) {
                errors.add(CommonValidatorUtil.isNegative(field.getName(), Double.valueOf((String) field.get(obj))));
            } else if (objectVal instanceof Integer) {
                errors.add(CommonValidatorUtil.isNegative(field.getName(), (Integer) field.get(obj)));
            }
```

Comment: i tried smth like (items[] instanceof String) but something is wrong

Comment: try (items[0] instanceof string)